# Treeselect vue.js - don't show item selected on input box

Tags: vue.js, vue-treeselect

is it possible to not show the selected items here?

[image]

Instead, I just want to show the placeholder which in this case it's "Select your favourite(s)...
So the final input would look like this:

[image]

Comment: What is the use case of this ? Why you don't want to show what you selected ?

Comment: For single select, I am able to achieve this by using `value-label` slot. If you are looking for that as well, I can help in that. Here you go - https://jsfiddle.net/tbny8sgo/

Answer (score 2):

You could set the `limit` prop to 0 to hide the selected items, and change the `limitText` prop.

```
<treeselect
  :multiple="true"
  :options="options"
  placeholder="Select your favourite(s)..."
  v-model="value"
  :limit="0"
  :limitText="() => 'Select your favourite(s)...'"
/>
```